# Web Worker in Webpack without `Worker-Loader`

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

How can a script use Javascript `imports` / `require` in a Web Workers script and bundle it up to using Webpack without using `Worker-Loader` or any other "plugin" abstraction — only using the browsers Web Worker API?

Via Webpack, I'm able to produce two scripts: `main.js` and `worker.js`. Webpack file is setup to transpile both files.

In `main.js` instantiate a new worker `const worker = new Worker('worker.js')`.

Worker script is simple:

```
/// worker.js

onmessage = function foo() {
  postMessage('test');
};
```

In `main.js`, `postMessage()` works as expected.

But once any module is imported into the worker, things break.

```
/// worker.js

import bar from 'bar';

onmessage = function foo() {
  postMessage('test');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `type: "module"` option you can pass to your [Worker's constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker):

```js
const worker = new Worker( url, { type: 'module' } );
```

Comment: Why do we need worker loader exactly? Can’t we do our job without worker loader?